# javascript object value in nodes

Tags: javascript

In the console log of `nodejs`. Trying to read an object within an object but the result is not correct. Here is what I'm trying to do:
Please bear with me its a bit difficult to read. Not sure how to format the correctly.

I ran this I get the following results.

```
console.log(Object.values(room));


[ 'helloRoom',
  'b19b29e4-c61f-4425-927e-4290a3e8b309mw',
  { 'b19b29e4-c61f-4425-927e-4290a3e8b309mw': 
     WebSocket {
       domain: null,
       _events: [Object],
       _eventsCount: 2,
       _maxListeners: undefined,
       readyState: 1,
       bytesReceived: 0,
       extensions: {},
       protocol: 'echo-protocol',
       _binaryType: 'nodebuffer',
       _finalize: [Function],
       _finalizeCalled: false,
       _closeMessage: null,
       _closeTimer: null,
       _closeCode: null,
       _receiver: [Receiver],
       _sender: [Sender],
       _socket: [Socket],
       _ultron: [Ultron],
       protocolVersion: 13,
       _maxPayload: 104857600,
       _isServer: true,
       id: 'b19b29e4-c61f-4425-927e-4290a3e8b309mw',
       room: 'b19b29e4-c61f-4425-927e-4290a3e8b309mw',
       is_host: true } },
  [ 'b19b29e4-c61f-4425-927e-4290a3e8b309mw' ],
  'b19b29e4-c61f-4425-927e-4290a3e8b309mw' ]
```

Then I ran this:

```
    for(var s in room){
        console.log(s);
       }
```

I get the following results:

```
name
id
sockets
users
host
```

Doing this:

```
console.log(room.id);
```

I get the following:

```
a5c6ac55-89a3-4f06-aace-81179674fdedmw
```

Doing this:
    console.log(Object.values(room.sockets));
I get:

```
[ WebSocket {
    domain: null,
    _events: { close: [Function], message: [Function: incoming] },
    _eventsCount: 2,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    readyState: 1,
    bytesReceived: 0,
    extensions: {},
    protocol: 'echo-protocol',
    _binaryType: 'nodebuffer',
    _finalize: { [Function: bound finalize] __ultron: 1 },
    _finalizeCalled: false,
    _closeMessage: null,
    _closeTimer: null,
    _closeCode: null,
    _receiver: 
     Receiver {
       _binaryType: 'nodebuffer',
       _extensions: {},
       _maxPayload: 104857600,
       _bufferedBytes: 0,
       _buffers: [],
       _compressed: false,
       _payloadLength: 0,
       _fragmented: 0,
       _masked: false,
       _fin: false,
       _mask: null,
       _opcode: 0,
       _totalPayloadLength: 0,
       _messageLength: 0,
       _fragments: [],
       _cleanupCallback: null,
       _hadError: false,
       _dead: false,
       _loop: false,
       onmessage: [Function],
       onclose: [Function],
       onerror: [Function],
       onping: [Function],
       onpong: [Function],
       _state: 0 },
    _sender: 
     Sender {
       _extensions: {},
       _socket: [Socket],
       _firstFragment: true,
       _compress: false,
       _bufferedBytes: 0,
       _deflating: false,
       _queue: [] },
    _socket: 
     Socket {
       connecting: false,
       _hadError: false,
       _handle: [TCP],
       _parent: null,
       _host: null,
       _readableState: [ReadableState],
       readable: true,
       domain: null,
       _events: [Object],
       _eventsCount: 7,
       _maxListeners: undefined,
       _writableState: [WritableState],
       writable: true,
       allowHalfOpen: false,
       _bytesDispatched: 168,
       _sockname: null,
       _pendingData: null,
       _pendingEncoding: '',
       server: [Server],
       _server: [Server],
       _idleTimeout: -1,
       _idleNext: null,
       _idlePrev: null,
       _idleStart: 4337,
       _destroyed: false,
       parser: null,
       on: [Function],
       _paused: false,
       read: [Function],
       _consuming: true,
       [Symbol(asyncId)]: 11,
       [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 0,
       [Symbol(asyncId)]: 13,
       [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 8 },
    _ultron: Ultron { id: 1, ee: [Socket] },
    protocolVersion: 13,
    _maxPayload: 104857600,
    _isServer: true,
    **id: 'a5c6ac55-89a3-4f06-aace-81179674fdedmw',**
    room: 'a5c6ac55-89a3-4f06-aace-81179674fdedmw',
    is_host: true } ]
```

What I want is the `room.socket.id`

I tried:

```
    console.log(room.sockets.id);
```

I get :

```
undefined
```

I tried:

```
 console.log(Object.values(room.sockets.id));
```

I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

How can I get `room.sockets.id` by itself?

[UPDATE]
The comment from Sutarmin Anton works.

"... room.sockets is actually an Object. Use

Object.keys(room.sockets)

which should get id's from keys of room.sockets object and retrurn you an array of them. Or, if you insist on getting id's from id property of every socket, do

Object.values(room.sockets).map(socket => socket.id) 
"

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `room.sockets` is an array, why are you expecting `id` property to be there? You possibly mean `room.sockets[0].id`.

Comment: You are trying to get property from array, not from object... So you have to use Array[index] & then property of that object.

Comment: I was able to retrieve the ids from room.sockets.id doing this

Comment: @Sutarmin Anton and Vishant chandra. Your suggested solution did not work, but doing this worked.        for(var s in room.sockets){
        console.log('sockets for loop:' + s); }   I'm still trying to find out how I can retrieve the room.sockets.ids directly without using a loop. 
      

   }

Comment: The socket object is put into the array like this room.sockets[ws.id] = socket;  I was table to retrieve room.sockets's value only using the ws.id that had been used as a key.  If this is the case then I'm guessing there should be some other ordered indexed for retrieving values?  The question should be how I can retrieved values of an array by index when the index of the array could be any id or number?

Comment: This is not making sense. if I do this for(var s in room.sockets){ console.log('sockets for loop:' + s); } I should get all of the info from the socket, not just the id.  When I did this    console.log(room.sockets); it showed me every element value in the object.

Comment: Ah, you want to get an array of all socket ids? If so, you need `room.sockets.map(socket => socket.id)`.

Comment: @SutarminAnton I get this error following your suggestion:  console.log(room.sockets.map(socket => socket.id));
                           ^

TypeError: room.sockets.map is not a function

Comment: I see, your `room.sockets` is actually an Object. You might need `Object.keys(room.sockets)` which should get id's from keys of `room.sockets` object and retrurn you an array of them. Or, if you insist on getting id's from `id` property of every `socket`, do `Object.values(room.sockets).map(socket => socket.id)`

Comment: @Sutarmin Anton your suggestion is working! I will update the original question with your answer, thank you!

Comment: @testingwebsocket, posted as answer, you may mark it as solution.

Comment: @Satarmin Anton, please excuse me for the noob question, where do I mark it as a solution?  Do I just click the up arrow and assume thats mark as solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need `Object.keys(room.sockets)` which should get id's from keys of `room.sockets` object and return you an array of them. Or, if you insist on getting id's from `id` property of every socket, do `Object.values(room.sockets).map(socket => socket.id)`